# How many digits should I use to calculate when I'm using the gravitational constants?

Tags: forces, newtonian-gravity, error-analysis

I had a question that  says: An astronaut steps out on the moon weighing 110kg. Calculate the gravity working on him.

I did 110 x 1,625 = 178,75 which rounded up gives 179N

The online textbook said 110 x 1,62 which gave 178N and so marked me wrong.

How do I know how many numbers in a constant I should use seeing as this is a big difference.
I sense this is a really simple question but thanks anyway.

Comment: The code running your online textbook is a classic example of bad code.  Such inflexibility, ignoring that there will normally be a small range of uncertainties in the correct answer, is indicative of a programmer who doesn't realize that there is some ambiguity in the precision of the number "110".

Comment: As David pointed out, this was actually just a matter of bad code. Still, it can be a good opportunity to learn about [significant figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures)

Comment: It's usually a good practice to include as many digits as possible in intermediate steps of a calculation, and then only round to the correct number of significant figures at the very end. This can greatly reduce the effect of rounding errors that accumulate during the calculation. The fact that you (a) included more digits of the moon's gravitational acceleration than the book's solution, (b) rounded to the right number of significant figures at the end, and (c) got a different answer than the book, points to a rounding error in the book's solution.

Comment: This seems like a good place to drop Henri Poincaré’s great saying: “What we call mass would seem to be nothing but an appearance, and all inertia to be of electromagnetic origin.”

Comment: This "constant" seems to regularly vary in tandem with recent length of day measurements on earth, which have been shown to have a 5.9 year period. This strongly suggests it is not in fact a "constant". "As a clue to what this "something else" is, the scientists note that the 5.9-year oscillatory period of the measured G values correlates almost perfectly with the 5.9-year oscillatory period of Earth's rotation rate, as determined by recent Length of Day (LOD) measurements." - https://phys.org/news/2015-04-gravitational-constant-vary.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the context of the question. In general, if the constants provided in the question has only a few significant figures, round your answer to the provided s.f. Typically, gravitational acceleration is rounded to 2 decimal places unless specified.

In the case above, it would be 1.62 m/s^2 (3 s.f.), and 110 kg (2 s.f. or 3s.f.), so the answer should be 3 s.f.

I hope it helps to solve your problem.